# Get row name of elements that are greater than a threshold user each column in matrix python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python , please can you help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFgPa.png)

I have read in an xlsx file and added headers to it

```
header = ['S.No', 'Name', 'Science', 'english','History','art','Maths']

df = pd.read_excel('matrix.xlsx',  header=None, names=header)
```

I would like to extract the student who achieved 85 and above, I would like it to look like the this:

```
roy[history,art,maths]
john[art,maths]
dave[art,math]
```

This is the code of how the excel file looks like to help

```
  p = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Roy', [80, 75, 85, 90, 95]), ('John', [75, 80, 75, 85, 100]), ('Dave', [80, 80, 80, 90, 95, ])],
               orient='index', columns=['Science', 'English', 'History', 'Arts', 'Maths'])
```

Thank you

Comment: [Please don't post your code or data as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The image is how the excel file looks like